# ConEmu Option Disabled: Startup - Autosave/restore opened tabs - Far folders also

Tags: conemu, far-manager

I want to be able to automatically restore proper folders in Far Manager's panels in ALL ConEmu tabs (not just the last closed one). However, the option in ConEmu **Startup - Autosave/restore opened tabs - Far folders also** is always disabled and unchecked, so I cannot check it:

[image: ConEmu options]

How do I enable this feature, so that when I start ConEmu, it will restore all Far processes and tabs with their proper folders?

Answer (score 1):

One way to change the startup directory is to manually edit your settings file, `ConEmu.xml`. This is most commonly going to located at `%appdata%/ConEmu.xml`.

Once you have the file open, search for the term `<key name="&lt;Startup&gt;"` then edit the `data` attribute of each `value` child element that represents a command prompt by the `name` attribute.

```
<key name="&lt;Startup&gt;" modified="2016-06-22 14:54:00" build="160619">
    <value name="GuiArgs" type="string" data=""/>
    <value name="Cmd1" type="string" data="-cur_console:d:C:\Dev\dashboard &quot;%ConEmuDir%\..\Git\git-cmd.exe&quot; --no-cd --command=usr/bin/bash.exe -l -i"/>
    <value name="Cmd2" type="string" data="&gt; -cur_console:fs1T50H -cur_console:d:C:\Dev\dashboard &quot;%ConEmuDir%\..\Git\git-cmd.exe&quot; --no-cd --command=usr/bin/bash.exe -l -i"/>
    <value name="Cmd3" type="string" data="-cur_console:bs1T50V -cur_console:d:C:\RethinkDB &quot;%ConEmuDir%\..\Git\git-cmd.exe&quot; --no-cd --command=usr/bin/bash.exe -l -i"/>
    <value name="Cmd4" type="string" data="-cur_console:bs2T50V -cur_console:d:C:\Dev\backend &quot;%ConEmuDir%\..\Git\git-cmd.exe&quot; --no-cd --command=usr/bin/bash.exe -l -i"/>
    <value name="Active" type="long" data="2"/>
    <value name="Count" type="long" data="4"/>
</key>
```